# How to fix "Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated"?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started learning android coding and I keep getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add these support library in build.gradle and also make sure the version of the support library(goto sdk manager and get the version number of sdk platform and place it in below dependancy because version of support library and sdk platform should be matched)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

[image]

Comment: How do I add the support libary? where do I include this code?
I would like to remind that this is literally my first time running this program.

Comment: Please check the above screenshot.i have edited the post.

Comment: I already have this code:
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'

Answer (score 2):

**Try any of the following**

1. Click `refresh` button on the preview pane

[image: refresh]

2. Sync Project with Gradle files

   Click *Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files*

[image: sync]

3. Rebuild Project
   Click *Build > Rebuild Project*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to come up periodically with Android Studio and it happened again today on an install I haven't used in a while. There may be more than one solution, but as of today June 08, 2016, I made sure two things are set:

1) Make sure you're on SDK/API 23 (or lower if necessary) vs the N preview, and

2) change the theme to "App theme". You may have to choose "Manifest Theme" in the left column before you can see "App Theme" show up as an option in the right column.

3) hit the refresh button (looks like two arrows in a circle)

Referring to a post above, both the support.appCompat and support.design libraries should be automatically added as dependencies to the gradle file, but you can double check them if necessary (and get the newest ones if the versions have changed).

You should see both of these:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

Why Google and Jet Brains can't keep this from happening I don't know, but as of today, it cleared the problem right away.